# double integral implementation in matlab

Tags: matlab, integral

I am in trouble to implement the following double integral. there is a summation inside the integral which make things a bit complicated. The matlab code I did is as follows and always has error like "Matrix dimensions must agree." , any hint to implement it? thanks

```
n=3;
nn=1:n;
aa=gamma([1:n])
thre=3;
lapha=4;
r=3;
fun1= @(theta, x) (1-sum( lambda *pi *( (x-r).^2+r^2-(x-r).*r.*cos(theta)).^(nn-1)./aa).*exp(-1*lambda *pi*((x-r).^2+r^2-(x-r).*r.*cos(theta)))).*lambda/n*(1-1/2^n).*thre.*r.^alpha.*(x-r).^(1-alpha) ;
answer=integral2( fun1, 0, 2*pi, 0, inf )
```

The double integral:
[image: the double integral]

Comment: You may want to break down your formula, work on individual pieces, and group them once they are validated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is the way you calculate the sum in the integrated function. The documentation of `intergal2` says that the function argument *must accept arrays X and Y of the same size and return an array of corresponding values*. But this expression inside the function definition:

```
((x-r).^2 + r^2 - (x-r).*r.*cos(theta)).^(nn-1)./aa
```

is not working the way you expect, because it's you who decide the size of `nn` and `aa`, while it's `integral2` that decides the size of the vectors `x` and `theta`; no wonder that there are disagreements on it.